# Streaming from windowsIoT to Windows using NAudio

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, win-universal-app, naudio, raspberry-pi2

I am having a very big issue streaming NAudio from windows IoT (NAudio Universal Library) on a raspberry pi 2, to NAudio on standard C#.

The microphone is on the raspberry pi and the issue seems to be that I cannot resample the format on the pi so when I send it over the wired to the regular computer it doesn't seem to know how to play it. I am using UDP (datagram on Raspberry pi, UDPListener or central PC).

My code is as follows for the raspberry pi:

```
        public void record()
    {

        if (recorder == null)
        {
            recorder = new WasapiCaptureRT();
            recorder.DataAvailable += RecorderOnDataAvailable;
        }

        if (reader != null)
        {
            reader.Dispose();
            reader = null;
        }
        recorder.StartRecording();

    }

 private async void RecorderOnDataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs waveInEventArgs)
    {
        if (reader == null)
        {
            recordStream = new MemoryStream();
            reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(recordStream, recorder.WaveFormat);

        }
            writer.WriteBytes(waveInEventArgs.Buffer);
            await writer.StoreAsync();



    }
```

And for the regular C#:

```
 public void test()
    {
        udpListener = new UdpClient(listenPort);
        IPEndPoint groupEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
        var _format = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(44100,1);


        waveOut = new WaveOut();
        waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(_format);
        waveProvider.BufferDuration = new TimeSpan(1,0,0);
        waveOut.Init(waveProvider);
        waveOut.Play();
        connected = true;
        var state = new ListenerThreadState { EndPoint = groupEP };
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ListenerThread, state);
    }

    private void ListenerThread(object state)
    {
        var listenerThreadState = (ListenerThreadState)state;
        var endPoint = listenerThreadState.EndPoint;
        try
        {
            while (connected)
            {
                byte[] b = udpListener.Receive(ref endPoint);
                waveProvider.AddSamples(b, 0, b.Length);

            }
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            // usually not a problem - just means we have disconnected
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!